# Class 'Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider' not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php, laravel-artisan

I'm working on a laravel project with my android phone.

I cleared junk files on the phone using a software and now I get error when trying to serve the laravel project.

First, I ran php artisan serve and got this error:

```
$ php artisan serve

In PackageManifest.php line 168:

  The /storage/emulated/0/web/tbcians/bootstrap
  /cache directory must be present and writable
  .
```

Then I created the cache directory and ran php artisan serve again and got another error:

```
$ php artisan serve

In ProviderRepository.php line 208:

  Class 'Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider'
   not found
```

How do I fix this?

I've tried running

```
$ composer update
```

and

```
$ composer update --no-scripts
```

but I'm still getting the error

Comment: 1. Remove "vendor" directory. Use "rm -rf vendor" if you in terminal
2. Remove composer.local file from root
3. Run "composer install"

Comment: That solved the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved the problem:

1. Remove "vendor" directory. Use "rm -rf vendor" if you in terminal
2. Remove composer.local file from root
3. Run "composer install"

– Jickson Johnson Koottala

Answer (score 0):

First clear your cache.`php artisan cache:clear`. Then `composer update`